# How to call results of a Boolean method in a main method 'static void'

Tags: java, eclipse, methods

I'm trying to create a `boolean` method called `hasBiggerTank` that if the **size** is bigger or equal to **4** it has enough fuel else not enough fuel.

I am trying to call results of a boolean method in a main method but the result I got is both car1 and car2 printing out the word `true` when it should output

**Expected output:**

> "goodfuel consumptions" plus car2 should be false.

I'm new to Java, I need some help.

```
// method
public boolean hasBiggerTank(int size) {
    if (size <= 4) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public class Start {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean hasBiggerTank = true;
        int size = 0;
        if (size <= 4) {
            System.out.println("Good fuel consumptions");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not enough fuel");
        }

        Car car1 = new Car();
        car1.hasBiggerTank(6);
        System.out.println("Car 1 efficiency: " + car1.hasBiggerTank(size));

        Car car2 = new Car();
        car2.hasBiggerTank(2);
        System.out.println("Car 2 efficiency: " + car2.hasBiggerTank(size));
    }
}
```

Comment: `if(size <= 4)`, no value has been assigned to `size` before that line, hence the error

Comment: @IsmaelPadilla - The variable `size` is a parameter in the function, which is being checked...

Comment: @AyushGarg - The above comments refer to an earlier version of the question where the variable `size` was not initialized in `main`.  Look at the question history.

Comment: @Mazzie - This is the kind of confusion that arises if you modify your question to replace earlier code / questions with newer ones.  **Please don't do that** .... in future.

Comment: Oh, okay @StephenC, thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean hasBiggerTank(int size) {            \\method
        if (size <= 4) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
} 


public class Start {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        
        int size = java.util.Scanner.nextInt();
        boolean hasBiggerTank = hasBiggerTank(size);
        if(hasBiggerTank) {
            System.out.println("Good Big Fuel Tank");
        }
        else { 
           System.out.println("Not big enough fuel Tank"); 
        }
   }
}
```

This is how to call a boolean returning method from main method.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I think that the *real* reason you are getting the wrong answer is that the *logic* of your `hasBiggerTank` method is incorrect.

Based on the name of the method, and the way you are using it, I think it is supposed to return `true` if and only if the car's tank size is bigger than the `size` argument.

But if you look at the code, that is NOT what you have implemented.  Instead, your method is *ignoring* the car's tank size, and is just testing if (in effect) the user has entered a number less or equal to 4.

Solution: think about `hasBiggerTank` should *really* be doing ... and implement that.

---

<sup>But there is also something odd about this whole thing.  In the real world a car's gas tank size and its fuel efficiency are *not the same thing*.  But perhaps this is just an artifact of an unrealistic set of requirements for a homework exercise ...</sup>

Answer (score 0):

as you said in question:

> that if the size is bigger or equal to 4 it has enough fuel else not enough fuel.

if the size is greater or equal to 4 then the method `hasBiggerTank` have to return `true` and the problem is with your condition inside `hasBiggerTank` method and you need to change it to this:

```
public static boolean hasBiggerTank(int size) {
    if (size >= 4) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

the next problem is in your `main()` method, again you are putting the conditions in wrong format which it should be changed to this:

```
int size = 0;
if (size >= 4) {
    System.out.println("Good fuel consumptions");
} else {
    System.out.println("Not enough fuel");
}
```

> in here according to your question we are checking whether the size is greater or equal to 4 or not if its true then **Good fuel consumptions** will be printed.